# Want to display (and count) rows that have zero out - SQL/SAS

Tags: sql, sas

[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyJo3.png)

I have tried the following SQL query already in SAS (if there is a better way to use SAS please let me know):

> Select *
>
> From [Database]
>
> Having COUNT(Month)>1 and SUM(Amount)=0;

This then only shows User_ID 003 and User_ID 004. The problem is I need it to show User_ID 001's first and third row since they offset (zero-out) in the same month along with 003 and 004. Basically, I am looking for duplicate values in certain columns with amounts that offset in a dataset that has 20,000+ rows (the Visual link above is not related to the dataset I am working on).

I have also tried separating the data so only positive numbers are in the Amount column and negative numbers are in a second Amount2 column and ran the query to find -Amount in Amount2. This didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about:    
Select Wanted_var from Table_in_db group by wanted_var having count(*)>1 and sum(amount) =0

Answer (score 0):

This will the user_ids where a duplicate case exists in a month

```
select a.user_id , a.month , amount
from my_table as a 
inner join my_table_a as b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
and a.month = b.month
and a.amount = -1 * b.amount
```